# selecting multiple images in gallery and display it's preview on the screen using MVVM Prism

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I would like to select multiple images in my gallery and the selected image should display on my screen. I can already select multiple images but I don't know how can I display its preview? I'm using Xamarin.MediaGallery plugin to select the image files. I am also using MVVM Prism

[This is the preview I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJZQQ.png)

Here is my view model

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IPageDialogService _pageDialogService;
    public DelegateCommand UploadPhotoCommand { get; set; }
    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService)
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        Title = "New Diary";
        UploadPhotoCommand = new DelegateCommand(UploadPhotoAsync);
        _pageDialogService = pageDialogService;          
    }

    private ImageSource _selectedImage;

    public ImageSource SelectedImage
    {
        get { return _selectedImage; }
        set {SetProperty (ref _selectedImage, value); }
    }

    private async void UploadPhotoAsync()
    {
        var results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(4, MediaFileType.Image);

        if (results?.Files == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var media in results.Files)
        {

            var fileName = media.NameWithoutExtension;
            var extension = media.Extension;
            var contentType = media.ContentType;

            await _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync(fileName, $"Extension: {extension}, Content-type: {contentType}", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

here is my View

```
    <StackLayout Margin="10">
        <Frame HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="5">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Add Photo to site diary" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image HeightRequest="80"
                           WidthRequest="80"
                           Source="{Binding SelectedImage}"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Add a photo" 
                        TextColor="White"
                        BackgroundColor="LawnGreen"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Command="{Binding UploadPhotoCommand}"/>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Include in photo gallery"/>
                    <CheckBox Color="LawnGreen" 
                              HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: if you want to display multiple items you would generally use a ListView or CollectionView

Comment: Yes understood. But how can I pass it to an imagesource since I used the MediaGallery plugin? I did an update on my post.

Comment: each MediaFile returned by the plugin can be opened as a stream, which you can use to create an ImageSource

Comment: Yes, that is when you are using CrossMedia plugin. But I am using the MediaGallery.
Can I use CrossMedia to select multiple images in the gallery?

Comment: the docs for **MediaGallery** clearly show that you can do `var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();`